# check string interpolation is empty or not in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to check if the value is empty or not.

```
Paid :  <h6 v-for="pai in PaidAmount">
             <b v-if="pai.billno==report.bill_no" >
             {{pai.paid + report.paid}}</b>                                       
         </h6>
```

if  `{{pai.paid + report.paid}}` is empty then i want to print only `{{report.paid}}`

Comment: `pai.paid + report.paid == '' ? report.paid : 'something else'`

Comment: I you are always going to display the `report.paid`, wouldn't the test really just be if `pai.paid` is empty?

Comment: if `{{pai.paid + report.paid}}` is empty then `{{report.paid}}` has to be empty as well - what do you want to print ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
   <h6 v-for="pai in PaidAmount">
                 <b v-if="pai.billno==report.bill_no" >
                 {{ (pai.paid + report.paid) ? (pai.paid + report.paid) : report.paid  }}
                 </b>            
             </h6>
```

[Reference Taken](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Comment: if string interoplation is empty then i want to print some message

Comment: check reference Please